# rebuilding/ rewriting a url to make it SEO friendly

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, links

I want my url to look like this **www.example.com/events/United+States**
instead of how it currently looks like which is **www.example.com/events/?country=United+States**. I'm not quite sure how to go about this. Here is my code

```
      <?php
        $some_url = site_url().'/events/';
        $params = array( 'country' => urlencode($counter) );
        $some_url = add_query_arg( $params, $some_url );

       ?>
     <a class="gpo_country" href="<?php echo $some_url ?>" >
```

Comment: What is `/events`? Is it a post type archive? A page?

Comment: @JacobPeattie /events is a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a rewrite rule using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) that will match a given path to query parameters:

```
function wpse_283774_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^events/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=events&country=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_283774_rewrite' );
```

This rule will match whatever is after `/events` as the `country` query parameter. Setting the third argument to `top` means that it will match our rule first, otherwise it will try to match whatever is after `/events` as a child page of `/events`.

Now we just need to register `country` as a valid query parameter:

```
function wpse_283774_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'country';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_283774_query_vars' );
```

Now in your template/functions you can get whatever comes after `/events` with `get_query_var( 'country' )`:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'country' ) ) {
    echo 'Events for ' . get_query_var( 'country' );
}
```

Just make sure to re-save your Permalinks settings after adding the code.

Comment: The solution did not work for me I put both functions in my functions.php file and when I re-saved my permalinks the rewrite rule was not added to my htaccess file.

Comment: It doesn't get added to your htaccess file. Use [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) to see if it's working.

Comment: Just tested it and it says that there are three rewrite rules that match the link. Could this potentially be the problem?

Comment: If there's a rule that takes priority over this one, then it's not going to work. What is the top result?

Comment: The top result is the rule that you created for me.

Comment: Some updated information. The rules you created for me sort of work. They led me to my default events page however they don't show specific  the events page for the particular country.

Comment: Well you have to handle that part using the `get_query_var` function. I don't know anything about your events system to know how that works. How have you been handling ?country=Whatever so far?

Comment: I retrieve all the events data from a plugin.

Comment: How? Do you do it yourself?

Comment: someone before me had setup the code in order get information.

Comment: It'll need to be changed to work this this type of URL.